# Track subdomains with Google Tag Manager and Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How can I track on Google Analytics subdomains using the Google Tag Manager service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://margari.net/digitalmarketing/tidy-subdomain-multidomain-metrics-google-tag-manager/#.UwxfdvnVh40

Hope this helps to get more details